# Refresh DataGridView in usercontrol from other usercontrol after changes

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-controls

I have a DataGridView in my usercontrol which I want to refresh when I make changes. For example when I click the save button in my other usercontrol the refresh function in the usercontrol with the DataGridView should be called. I have searched for solutions for this problem but none of them solved my problem (I tried ResetBindings, setting the DataSource to null and set DataSource again etc). To call a usercontrol from another usercontrol I use instances.

```
   public partial class incidentTypeSearchControl : UserControl
{
    public static incidentTypeSearchControl Instance { get; set; }
    REINVENT_QualityDataSet reinventQualityDataset = new REINVENT_QualityDataSet();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
    REINVENT_QualityDataSetTableAdapters.IncIncidentTypeTableAdapter incidentTypeAdapter =
        new REINVENT_QualityDataSetTableAdapters.IncIncidentTypeTableAdapter();

    public incidentTypeSearchControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this;
        this.dataGridView1.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick);
    }

    private void incidentTypeSearchControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                   
        incidentTypeAdapter.Fill(reinventQualityDataset.IncIncidentType);

        source.DataSource = reinventQualityDataset.IncIncidentType;

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;           
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = reinventQualityDataset.IncIncidentType;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Id";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Incidenttype";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Categorie";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Tellen in statistiek";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Punten";            
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Faalkosten";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Kostendrager";

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        }          
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;

    }
    //added/      
    public DataGridView myDataGrid
    {
        get { return dataGridView1; }
        set { dataGridView1 = value; }
    }

    public void updateDataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
        source.ResetBindings(true);
    }
```

In other usercontrol I can access the datagridview like this:

```
    incidentTypeSearchControl.Instance.myDataGrid // access datagridview
```

Calling the updateGridView() method sets the grid header texts back to default (which is not the intention) and the values in the datagridview aren't updated. How to make a
method to refresh/update my datagridview and call this method from my other usercontrol?

UPDATE:

Problem solved by filling the dataset again

Answer (score 0):

try

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = typeof(IncIncidentTypeDataTable); // or whatever type is your source
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: This sets the header texts to default but doesn't update the values.

Comment: I update the values with the updateGridView() method. At the moment this method sets the column header texts to default and updates nothing. So how can I fix this?

Comment: that's strange, if you're using BindingSource, you shouldn't have to reset datagridview's DataSource at all. If you have a DataTable that is the DataSource of BindingSource, that then is the DataSource of your GridView, then all changes you make on the underlying DataTable should propagate to DGV, eventually bindingSource.ResetBindings(false) or bnindingSOurce.EndEdit() should be doing the trick...

Comment: I have solved my issue by filling the dataset again. Thnx for your help anyway